# Get return value from ExecuteSqlRaw in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an extremely large table that I'm trying to get the number of rows for. Using `COUNT(*)` is too slow, so I want to run this query using EF Core:

```
int count = _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
                "SELECT  Total_Rows = SUM(st.row_count) " +
                "FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats st " +
                "WHERE   object_name(object_id) = 'MyLargeTable' AND(index_id < 2)");
```

The only problem is that the return value isn't the result of the query, but the number of records returned, which is just 1

Is there a way to get the correct value here, or will I need to use a different method?

Comment: Add some sample data and expected results. Look at your `WHERE` clause, it would seem to me that your example is returning results correctly, you should look at modifying your query. Also, `COUNT` and `SUM` are not the same, so which is it that you want? `COUNT(*)` should be relatively fast, how slow, is slow? If the row has an identity column you could select the top 1 row ordered by identity descending and get the number unless of course you are deleting rows from this table. What are you using for your database? ie. SQL Server, MySQL, etc.?

Comment: https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/05/26/ef-core-fromsql-scalar.html

Comment: This scalar blog should be considered a valid answer...

Comment: Using plain ADO.Net is so much easier for this kind of queries. Just borrow EF's connection and you're almost done.

Answer (score 6):

Since you only need a scalar value you can also use an output parameter to retrieve the data, eg

```
                var sql = @"
SELECT @Total_Rows = SUM(st.row_count) 
FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats st 
WHERE   object_name(object_id) = 'MyLargeTable' AND(index_id < 2)
";
                var pTotalRows = new SqlParameter("@Total_Rows", System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt);
                pTotalRows.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql, pTotalRows);

                var totalRows = (long?)(pTotalRows.Value == DBNull.Value ? null:pTotalRows.Value) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If one let's me to recreate a correct answer based on this blog: https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/05/26/ef-core-fromsql-scalar.html

1. We need to create a virtual entity model for our database, that will contain our needed query result, at the same time we need a pseudo `DbSet<this virtual model>` to use ef core `FromSqlRaw` method that returns data instead of `ExecuteSqlRaw` that just returns numbers of rows affected by query.

The example is for returning an integer value, but you can easily adapt it:

Define a return value holding class

```
public class IntReturn
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Fake a virtual `DbSet<IntReturn>` it will not be really present in db:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            ...

            modelBuilder.Entity<IntReturn>().HasNoKey();

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

2. Now we can call FromSqlRaw for this virtual set. In this example the calling method is inside MyContext:DbContext, you'd need to instantiate your own context to use it instead of `this`):

NOTE the usage of `"as Value"` - same name as `IntReturn.Value` property. In some wierd cases you'd have to do the opposite: name your virtual model property after the name of the value thre database funstion is returning.

```
 public int ReserveNextCustomerId()
            {
                var sql = $"Select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('\"Customers\"', 'Id')) as Value;";
    
                var i = this.Set<IntReturn>()
                .FromSqlRaw(sql)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .First().Value;
    
                return i;
            }
```